# UnityWebRequest fail at bad connection, and doesn’t recover when connection is restored

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, http, networking, broken-pipe

So I have an application that uses UnityWebRequest to communicate with server using http

I’m also using Charles to simulate bad internet connection, but the problem also happens in real life scenarios

So I’m playing the game, everything is fine, then I make my internet connection bad and after a while I get `Socket: Broken pipe (Write failed)` failure on my requests. No problem so far, connection is super bad, so that’s expected.

But then I make my connection good again, but requests never recover. Instantly after sending a request, I get the same error, for all my requests, all the time.

Problem resolves itself after I move the app into background and back.

I’ve exhausted all my knowledge and ideas on how to fix the problem and I’m stuck. So please, what could be a reason for this happening and how can I solve this?

I’ve checked every piece of my code that gets invoked when app moves into background or foreground, but it doesn’t help. Only actually doing that helps.

Going by the answer to [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-fails-after-internet-loss-regain.985403/), I've tried disabling [useHttpContinue](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-useHttpContinue.html) for my requests, but it doesn't help either

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example of your web request code so the community can reproduce your exact issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.